# Parcelable List<string>, List<int>

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, parcelable

I am having issues using `Parcelable` to pass List that are within my class. The values for my strings (partNbr and partdescription) are passing through ok, but I am losing the list somewhere between the Write and Read.

I have not had much luck with going the Serializable or `JSON` route, but if someone can provide a good c# example of what I am needing.

I am open to trying again.  Am I reading the values in wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Related code is posted below.

```
public class Part : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public string partNbr { get; set; }
    public string partDescription { get; set; }
    public List<string> uomList { get; set; }
    public List<int> qtyList { get; set; }

    #region IParcelable Implementation

    private static readonly PartXParcelableCreator<Part> _creator = 
        new PartXParcelableCreator<Part>((parcel) => new Part(parcel));

    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static PartXParcelableCreator<Part> GetCreator()
    {
        return _creator;
    }
    public Part(Parcel parcel)
    {
        partNbr = parcel.ReadString();
        partDescription = parcel.ReadString();
        parcel.ReadStringList(uomList);
        parcel.ReadList(qtyList, null);
    }


    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        //debugging here shows a count of 3 items in uomList and 6 in qtyList
        dest.WriteString(partNbr);
        dest.WriteString(partDescription);
        dest.WriteStringList(uomList);
        dest.WriteList(qtyList);
    }
    #endregion



}

public class PartXParcelableCreator<T> : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
    where T : Java.Lang.Object, new()
{
    private readonly Func<Parcel, T> _createFunc;

    public PartXParcelableCreator(Func<Parcel, T> createFromParcelFunc)
    {
        _createFunc = createFromParcelFunc;
    }

    #region IParcelableCreator Implementation
    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        //tried debugging source values here, but List values are null at this point
        return _createFunc(source);
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new T[size];
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the JSON.NET package.  It's very easy to use and well documented

Comment: I am trying that, but the object is coming out null in the next activity.  Here is the code where I am serializing the object:   intent.PutExtra("PART", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPart)); and where I am deserializing:  Part inPart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Part>(Intent.GetStringExtra("PART"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason said, you could try using `JSON.NET` package.

> I am trying that, but the object is coming out null in the next activity.

Don't extends the `Java.Lang.Object`, modify your `Part` class like this :

```
public class Part
{
    public string partNbr { get; set; }
    public string partDescription { get; set; }
    public List<string> uomList { get; set; }
    public List<int> qtyList { get; set; }
}
```

Then it should be work.

Comment: If I could upvote this 100x I would.  Thank you guys a lot!  I have fooled around with this for far longer than I would like to admit.